# Unable to install Ubuntu 22.04 on Supermicro SYS-2029P-C1RT via IPMI

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb-installation, ipmi

I had attached the Ubuntu ISO to Virtual Storage option via IPMI(Supermicro) and Booted via USB.
ISO is booting up and going directly to "Try Ubuntu" instead of actual installation. It does not prompt for the installation methods/options.
Once the "Try Ubuntu" is available and when I try to start the actual installation, it is failing with "You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu". Attached screenshot for the same.
Can some one help on the best way to install the Ubuntu via IPMI. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAVVI.jpg)

Comment: Did you verify the ISO you downloaded? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: I had used the same image on my local VMware workstation and it works fine. It initially gets into "try ubuntu" mode and I can continue install the actual OS from there. Is there a  procedure specially for IPMI which uses serial console?
I had installed CentOS on other similar Machines, basically I had installed via Text mode instead of Graphical mode. I am not able to find such option for Ubuntu.